# What's the sample space for this conditional-urn problem?

Tags: probability

Urn $1$ has $3$ white balls, $4$ black balls. Urn $2$ has $4$ whites
and $3$ blacks. Pick a ball from urn $1$. (You're always suppose to
return the ball to the urn.) If the ball is white, pick the next from
urn $1.$ If it's black, pick from the other urn. (Keep doing it as
such.)

What's the sample space for this problem? I'd say this is the sample 
space. Let $Bn(color, urn)$ represent the extraction. For example, 
$B1(w, 1)$ means ball $1$ (first ball) is white taken from urn $1$. $B2(b, 1)$ means ball $2$ (second ball) is black taken from urn $1.$

So the sample space begins with $B1(w, 1), B1(b, 1).$ We cannot take $B1$ 
from urn $2$ because it's the first ball. For the second however, I'm 
gonna have $4$ possibilities:

$B2(w, 1), B2(w, 2), B2(b, 1), B2(b, 2)$

How about the third ball? I'm gonna have another $4$ possibilities.

$B3(w, 1), B3(w, 2), B3(b, 1), B3(b, 2)$

To this is my sample space. (Continuing in this fashion.)

What's the size of this sample space?

Except for the first extraction, I'm gonna have $4$ possibilities. If I 
limit myself to $10$ extractions, then my sample space is $4 \cdot 9 + 2 = 38$ 
outcomes. For $n$ extractions, I have $4(n - 1) + 2$.

Can you check and advise?

Comment: If you must write the sample space, it's often best to strive for simplicity. The sample space does not have to explain the _process._ Here it may be convenient to keep track of 4-tuples $(w1, b1, w2, b2),$ showing numbers of white and black balls in each urn. But because total numbers of white and black are fixed, it would sufficient to keep track only of what's in the first urn $(w1, b1).$ At every step in time you define a different random variable on the sample space according to the probability rules of the process.

Comment: Thank you for the insight.  I must confess I'm rather a newbie here.  My understanding of your comment is that if I can describe all possible urn states, then I have described the sample space.  This makes sense to me.  (You even mention that describing one urn is enough.  That makes sense to me too.)  Picking the first ball, urn 1 can be either $(3w, 3b)$ or $(2w, 4b)$.  If it's black, I must pick from urn urn 2 and then urn 2 can be either $(3w, 3b)$ or $(4w, 2b)$.  Since I always put the picked ball back, then there is no other variation.

Comment: Hence --- using the 4-tuples --- the sample space can be described as $\{(3w, 3b, 4w, 3b), (2w, 4b, 4w, 3b), (3w, 4b, 3w, 3b), (3w, 4b, 4w, 2b)\}$.  This looks correct to me.  It was much simpler than I thought.  (I wish I could mark your comment as a correct answer.)  Thank you!

Comment: @BruceET I've asked a second related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2718175).  I'd appreciate if you also give it some of your attention.  Thanks in advance.