# How to solve an urn-problem which involves a condition for extracting the next ball?

Tags: probability

Urn $1$ has $3$ white balls, $4$ black balls. Urn $2$ has $4$ whites
and $3$ blacks. Pick a ball from either urn. (You're always suppose to
return the ball to the urn.) If the ball is white, pick the next from
urn $1.$ If it's black, pick the next from urn $2.$ (Keep doing it as
such.)

I ask two questions here.

What's the probability that the first ball is white?  That's very easy.  The first ball will be extracted from either urn.  There are $14$ balls total and $7$ are white, so the probability of it being white is just $7/14 = 1/2$.

Given that the first ball comes from urn $1$, what's the probability that the second ball is white?  I don't know how to answer this one.

---

At first I thought it could be a direct application of the conditional probability definition, but there's a conditional going on which tells me the question isn't that easy.  I've been taught one theorem which is probably meant to be used here: the law of total probability.  Can you help me see how this theorem sort of encodes this conditioning, giving us a solution to this problem?

---

EDIT: From Graham Kemp's answer:

$$\begin{align}
P(B_2{=}w\mid D_1{=}1) =&~ { P(B_2{=}w\mid D_2{=}1)~ P(D_2{=}1\mid D_1{=}1)\\+
P(B_2{=}w\mid D_2{=}2)~ P(D_2{=}2\mid D_1{=}1)}
\\[2ex] =&~ {P(B_2{=}w\mid D_2{=}1)~P(B_1{=}w\mid D_1{=}1)\\+P(B_2{=}w\mid D_2{=}2)~ P(B_1{=}b\mid D_1{=}1)}
\\[2ex] =&~ \frac{P(B_2{=}w \cap D_2{=}1)}{P(D_2{=}1)} \frac{P(D_2){=}1 \cap D_1{=}1)}{P(D_1{=}1)}\\+ \frac{P(B_2{=}2 \cap D_2{=}2)}{P(D_2{=}2)} \frac{P(D_2{=}2 \cap D_1{=}1)}{P(D_1{=}1)}
\\[2ex] =&~ \frac{3/7 \times 3/7}{3/7} \frac{3/7}{1} +\frac{4/7 \times 4/7}{4/7} \frac{4/7}{1}
\\[2ex] =&~ \frac{9}{49} + \frac{16}{49} = \frac{25}{49}
\end{align}$$

(I'll appreciate if you shift that addition-term to the right.  Not sure how to do it.)

Comment: Since you are given that the first ball comes from urn 1, the probability that the second ball comes from urn 1 is 3/7.  So it is just a straightforward calculation with conditional probabilities.

Comment: @saulspatz Let's say the first ball (from urn 1) is white.  What's the probability the next ball is white?  That has to be 3/7 as you say because being white I'm supposed to pick the next from urn 1.  However, what if the first ball is black?  Then the probability the next is white is 4/7 --- because I'd then pick the second one from urn 2.  (So I have two possible answers here.)  I don't know how to deal with this conditioning.

Comment: Look at Graham Kemp's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > If the ball is white, pick the next from urn 1. If it's black, pick the next from urn 2.
>
> Given that the first ball comes from urn 1, what's the probability that the second ball is white? I don't know how to answer this one.

You know the probability that a ball is white when drawn from a particular urn.  You are given that the first draw is from urn 1.

When given that, what is the probability that the second ball is drawn from urn 1 *and* white?    Well, it is the probability that a ball is white when drawn from urn 1 times the probability that it is white when drawn from urn 2.

Likewise, what is the probability that the second ball is drawn from urn 2 *and* white?

So, now, what is total probability that the second ball is white , when given that start?

---

Let $B_n$ be the colour of the ball from draw $n$, and $D_n$ be the number of the urn from which it is drawn. Then, as we are told, $\{D_{n+1}{=}1\} =\{B_n{=}w\}$ and $\{D_{n+1}{=}2\} =\{B_n{=}b\}$. So under the condition that $D_1=1$

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(B_2{=}w\mid D_1{=}1) =&~ \mathsf P(B_2{=}w\cap (D_2{=}1\cup D_2{=}2)\mid D_1{=}1)
\\[2ex] =&~ {\mathsf P(B_2{=}w\mid D_2{=}1)~\mathsf P(D_2{=}1\mid D_1{=}1)\\+\mathsf P(B_2{=}w\mid D_2{=}2)~\mathsf P(D_2{=}2\mid D_1{=}1)}
\\[2ex] =&~ {\mathsf P(B_2{=}w\mid D_2{=}1)~\mathsf P(B_1{=}w\mid D_1{=}1)\\+\mathsf P(B_2{=}w\mid D_2{=}2)~\mathsf P(B_1{=}b\mid D_1{=}1)}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks for using the law of total probability.  I fail to see which partition you're using.  It seems you've partition only the sample space for urn 1.  Doesn't the sample space cover urn 2 too?  Shouldn't your partition cover urn 2?

Comment: @JoepAwinita The partition is over the urn of the second draw, which in turn is determined by the ball of the first draw.  The *given* condtion is that the urn of the first draw is urn #1.

Comment: Thanks for your notation.  I can't say the problem is clear to me, but I've managed to get the right answer.  (I'm adding it as an EDIT to the question.)  For one, I didn't expect to see conditional probabilities in every factor of the total probability theorem.  I'm used to seeing $P(E|G) P(G)$ and not $P(E|G) P(G|G2)$.  Please recommend something?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

By law of total probability,
\begin{align}
&P( \text{ second ball is white}| \text{first ball from urn }1)\\
&=P( \text{ second ball is white}| \text{first ball is white and from urn }1)P( \text{ first ball is white}| \text{first ball from urn }1) + P( \text{ second ball is white}| \text{first ball is black and from urn }1)P( \text{ first ball is black }| \text{first ball from urn }1)\\
&=P( \text{ second ball is white}| \text{first ball is white})P( \text{ first ball is white}| \text{first ball from urn }1)+ P( \text{ second ball is white}| \text{first ball is black})P( \text{ first ball is black}| \text{first ball from urn }1)\\
\end{align}

Try to complete it.

Comment: To use the law of total probability, I need a partition.  I fail to see which partition you're using.  It seems your partition is "first ball is white | first ball from urn 1" union "second ball is black | first ball from urn 1".  But is this a partition of the sample space?

Comment: I made a typo previously, I condition on the color of first ball.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to call the probability that we pick a white on our first go(and therefore enter urn 1)   P<sub>first</sub>, and the probability of entering the second urn P<sub>second</sub>.

As the question states that we started on Urn 1, we first need to find P<sub>first</sub> and P<sub>second</sub>.

As there are 7 balls in Urn 1, of which 3 are white, P<sub>first</sub> = 3/7. Thus, P<sub>second</sub> = 4/7.

If we are then in the first urn (if P<sub>first</sub> is true), the P<sub>SecondChoiceWhite1</sub> = 3/7. If we are in the second urn, P<sub>SecondChoiceWhite2</sub> = 4/7 (urn 2 has 7 balls, of which 4 are white).

Thus, the odds of choosing a white ball first (entering urn 1) then choosing another white ball is P<sub>first</sub> * P<sub>SecondChoiceWhite1</sub> = 3/7 * 3/7 = 9/49.

The odds of choosing a black ball first (entering urn 2) then choosing a white ball is P<sub>second</sub> * P<sub>SecondChoiceWhite2</sub> = 4/7 * 4/7 = 16/49.

Finally, the total probability of the second choice being white is 9/49 + 16/49 = 25/49.

N.B I've not done combinatorics in a fairly long time, but I'm pretty sure this is right. I'm more than happy to be corrected.

Comment: So my answer ended up matching yours, but I needed to relate this problem to the total probability theorem.  You solved it by your own argument in a quick fashion.  I couldn't match it with my the tools I had to use.  Nevertheless, I appreciate your answer.  Thank you.